# Android imageView Rotation + Zoom In Out

Tags: android, android-imageview

how do I make an imageview rotate and be able to zoom in and out. The following is able to make either the imageView rotate or zoom in and out, but not both. I think the problem is when an image is touch, it will just trigger to touch event of the zoom in and out, so the rotation is skip. How do I combine these 2 functions into 1 so that the image can rotate and zoom in and out at the same time. Thank you.

Here's the code that is able to do the zoom in and out.

```
   public class PinchZoomActivity extends Activity implements 
 OnTouchListener, RotationGestureDetector.OnRotationGestureListener
 {
private static final String TAG = "Touch";
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f,MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

// These matrices will be used to scale points of the image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;
private RotationGestureDetector mRotationDetector;
private float angle;
private ImageView view;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mRotationDetector = new RotationGestureDetector(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;

    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:   // first finger down only
            /*savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
            mode = DRAG;*/
         // first finger down only
             matrix.set(view.getImageMatrix());
             savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

            mode = NONE;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 5f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
                Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            if (mode == DRAG)
            {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix  of points
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM)
            {
                // pinch zooming
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 5f)
                {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                    // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                    // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                    // zoom out
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                }
            }
            break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: spacing Parameters: MotionEvent Returns: float Description:
 * checks the spacing between the two fingers on touch
 * ----------------------------------------------------
 */

private float spacing(MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return (float)Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Method: midPoint Parameters: PointF object, MotionEvent Returns: void
 * Description: calculates the midpoint between the two fingers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event)
{
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE","POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
    {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }

    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
    {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }

    sb.append("]");
    Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector) {
    angle = rotationDetector.getAngle();
    Log.d("RotationGestureDetector", "Rotation: " + Float.toString(angle));
    view.setRotation(view.getRotation() + (-angle));
    //imgPhoto.setRotation(imgPhoto.getRotation() + (-angle));
}
 }
```

Here's the code to make the imageView rotate

```
 public class RotationGestureDetector {
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private float fX, fY, sX, sY;
private int ptrID1, ptrID2;
private float mAngle;

private OnRotationGestureListener mListener;

public float getAngle() {
    return mAngle;
}

public RotationGestureDetector(OnRotationGestureListener listener){
    mListener = listener;
    ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ptrID1 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            ptrID2 = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
            sX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
            sY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
            fX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
            fY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(ptrID1 != INVALID_POINTER_ID && ptrID2 != INVALID_POINTER_ID){
                float nfX, nfY, nsX, nsY;
                nsX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                nsY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID1));
                nfX = event.getX(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));
                nfY = event.getY(event.findPointerIndex(ptrID2));

                mAngle = angleBetweenLines(fX, fY, sX, sY, nfX, nfY, nsX, nsY);

                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.OnRotation(this);
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            ptrID1 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            ptrID2 = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private float angleBetweenLines (float fX, float fY, float sX, float sY, float nfX, float nfY, float nsX, float nsY)
{
    float angle1 = (float) Math.atan2( (fY - sY), (fX - sX) );
    float angle2 = (float) Math.atan2( (nfY - nsY), (nfX - nsX) );

    float angle = ((float)Math.toDegrees(angle1 - angle2)) % 360;
    if (angle < -180.f) angle += 360.0f;
    if (angle > 180.f) angle -= 360.0f;
    return angle;
}

public static interface OnRotationGestureListener {
    public void OnRotation(RotationGestureDetector rotationDetector);
}
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by rotation ? is it portrait or landscap.

Comment: I mean to rotate an image by two fingers, not the portrait or landscape.

Comment: try this https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView